# Compactness of units in ring of integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory, locally-compact-groups

Question : Let $\nu$ be a non-archimedean valuation on a number field $k$. Is $\mathcal{O}_{\nu}^{*}$ ( the set of units in ring of integers) compact under subspace topology of $k_{\nu}$ (completion of $k$ under $\nu$)?

I have proven that it is locally compact but it is not apparently clear to me whether it is compact or not.

Comment: How much knowledge about $p$-adic fields is one allowed to use here? Also, how have you proved local compactness, maybe there is an easy refinement of that proof?

Comment: Earlier you showed a proof of local compactness which relied on the true assertion that $k_\nu$ is locally compact. But how was this assertion proven? A proof for that might be refined to what you want.

Comment: I think I have got the solution though, thanks for your help. We can use the compactness of $\mathcal{O}_{\nu}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\nu}^*$ being closed subset of $\mathcal{O}_{\nu}$.

Comment: That's sort of what I mean, if you know compactness of that ring of integers ...